# How to configure subdomains in nginx

Tags: nginx

I am trying to load another website into my subdomain using reverse proxy in `Nginx`
for example

```
www.example.com is my website
test.example.com is my subdomain
```

and I want to load [www.facebook.com](http://www.facebook.com) into the subdomain

Now if the user enters `test.example.com` Facebook will be loaded into this subdomain and I also have access to use its content, like I will be able to getelementbytag etc.

Please tell me how to do that, with proper steps because I am new in `Nginx`. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here I just took this from one of my projects. It demonstrated that the `server_name` you specify in each server block will be matched against the host header in the incoming request.

```c
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    
    # my domain
    server_name mydomain.dev;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    include /etc/nginx/snippets/ssl.conf;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2 ;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    # my sub domain
    server_name foobar.mydomain.dev;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://foobarbaz.website-eu-central-1.linodeobjects.com/;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply bro, but I am not understanding these concepts if you can explain to me in detail all steps from start to end it would be much helpful for me.